# Ampliar tamaño del contenido de un TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

Quisiera saber cómo puedo ajustar el tamaño de los elementos que añado dentro del TabItem (normalmente será un Grid) desde código.

Yo tengo un TabControl creado sin ningún elemento:
`<TabControl x:Name="tabVentanas" Margin="154,116,0,0"/>`

En tiempo de ejecución yo le voy añadiendo las pestañas (TabItems) cuando hago click en un botón. Le indico el nombre de la cabecera y luego le inserto mi control como el contenido del TabItem:

```
TabItem newTabItem = new TabItem()
{
   Header= nombre
};
UserControl1 ctl = new UserControl1(entity);
newTabItem.Content = ctl;
tabVentanas.Items.Add(newTabItem);
```

Después añado dicho TabItem al TabControl.

Lo que quiero saber es cómo puedo hacer para que, el control que yo añado dentro del TabItem ocupe todo el TabItem.

Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: prueba a poner la propiedad (creo que era Dock) a Fill del elemento

Comment: @Veelicus el elemento no tiene dicha propiedad

Comment: @Veelicus es wpf, no winforms.

Comment: ah, perdona, no me di cuenta, yo de wpf, poco, de hecho quiero aprenderlo cuando tenga tiempo, un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los controles en  WPF tienen varias propiedades heredadas de `FrameworkElements`. En este caso, a ti te interesarían [`HorizontalAlignment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment(v=vs.110).aspx) y [`VerticalAlignment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.verticalalignment(v=vs.110).aspx), que debes poner a `Stretch` en tu control. Sería algo asi:

```
UserControl1 ctl = new UserControl1(entity);
ctl.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
ctl.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
newTabItem.Content = ctl;
tabVentanas.Items.Add(newTabItem);
```

Esto haría que tu control ocupase todo el espacio disponible en su contenedor (en este caso,el `TabItem`)

Al estar añadiendo los `TabItem` por código, es posible que necesites hacer lo mismo para ellos:

```
TabItem newTabItem = new TabItem()
{
    Header = nombre,
    HorizontalAlignment= HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
    VerticalAlignment= VerticalAlignment.Stretch
};
```

---

Es importante añadir que para que estas propiedades funcionen, las propiedades `Width` y `Height` no deben tener valor, ya que si es así este valor "manda" sobre `HorizontalAlignment` y `VerticalAlignment`.

Comment: Vale, confirmo que si quitas las propiedades Width y Height del componente y sigues esos pasos también funciona =D

Comment: Si, como digo @Oscar tienen preferencia Width y Height. Lo normal es que en la definición de tu usercontrol pongas las propiedades `HorizontalAlignment` y `VerticalAlignment` y asi en el código no tienes que hacer nada. Me alegro que te haya funcionado :)

Answer (score 1):

Ya había probado con el HorizontalAlignment y el VerticalAlignment y no me funcionaba.
Lo que si me ha funcionado es lo siguiente:

```
UserControl1 ctl = new UserControl1(entity);
ctl.Width = Double.NaN;
ctl.Height = Double.NaN;
newTabItem.Content = ctl;
tabVentanas.Items.Add(newTabItem);
```

Asignándole al Width y al Height el Double.Nan, creo que se lo toma como el "Auto". Con eso ya me lo ocupa todo.

Comment: Si, `Double.NaN`se puede usar como "Auto"...lo que me parece raro es que no te funcionase el `HorizontalAlignment` y el `VerticalAlignment`. Es posible que fuera alguna cosa en tu xaml,pero si asi te funciona perfecto.

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, el problema puede estar en tu `UserControl`. Si en su definición tenias puestas las propiedades `Width` y `Height`, estas mandan sobre los Horizontal y Vertical alignments. Voy a añadir eso a mi respuesta para que quede claro

Comment: Ok, ahora le echo un ojo y te confirmo si puede ser eso